# Upload documents to file share through Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

We have a file share that we would like to keep, but have it mapped to sharepoint so it can be searched. I know I can do this with a page viewer web part, but is it also possible to upload documents to the drive through Sharepoint?

I am not able to find a solution that accomplishes both viewing and uploading to the share. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you all have Nintex enabled?  If so you can create a workflow that will copy a document to the file share or you can create a workflow that will manage syncing the files back in forth.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Not sure if we have Nintex enabled or not. Basically, they don't want to touch the file share. Sharepoint is just going to be like a front-end to upload new docs and view what is there. Would an external list work for this?

Comment: Look into an event handler.  You can write a custom event handler to send the documents to the file share.  Just keep in mind that SharePoint has limitations when it comes to uploading documents.